# How do I write to .csv from text entry?

Tags: python, csv, tkinter

I'm working on my computing project for school, and I'm having trouble getting anything the user inputs to save to a .csv file. I'm using Python 3.2.2 and Tkinter as the GUI. No matter what I enter into the fields I get the wrong output into the csv, similar to ".54540776.54541280," etc. I've basically had to teach myself this stuff as I've gone along so I'm probably just making a stupid mistake somewhere. I've tried using the csv module in Python and I can't get that working. I haven't been able to find anything similar (that I understand to be the same anyway). I've uploaded my code to pastebin to make it more readable: http://pastebin.com/FarMtWdZ

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're printing out the Entry objects themselves, not the values they contain. I'm not too familiar with tkinter, but I think you need to call a get() method to get the text.

I'd also suggest reviewing some basic software design resources, ideally some specific to Python. There are a lot of weirdnesses/unnecessary bits in your code.

Comment: I definitely need to tidy up and improve on how I work, and I'll be sure to look into some stuff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*note: I didn't read all of the code, but this addresses the crux of the problem.*

The problem is with how you are pulling the contents of an `Entry`.  Don't use `str(your_entry)`, rather use `your_entry.get()`.

```
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()
e = Entry(root)
e.insert(0, "a default value")
e.pack()
print "str(e)  =>", str(e)  # str() just gives us Tk's internal identifier
print "e.get() =>", e.get() # use get() for contents of Entry
root.mainloop()
```

gives

```
str(e)  => .33906776
e.get() => a default value
```